# How to scrape the output of widgets on a website using python/scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the ads on a site...

This site for example

http://www.bestyling.com/15-of-the-most-expensive-shoes-ever-and-you-wont-believe-whats-1/?utm_source=Ourbrain&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=15%20Shoes%20-%20Desktop%20USA

i am trying to get the ads from from this a

/html/body[@class='single single-post postid-171 single-format-standard custom-background hasGoogleVoiceExt']/div[@id='site']/div[@id='site-out']/div[@id='site-fixed']/div[@id='content-out']/div[@id='content-in']/div[@id='main-content-wrap']/div[@id='main-content-contain']/div[@id='content-wrap']/div[@class='sec-marg-out4 relative']/div[@class='sec-marg-in4']/article[@class='post-171 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized']/div[@id='post-area']/div[@class='post-body-out']/div[@class='post-body-in']/div[@id='content-area']/div[@class='content-area-cont left relative']/div[@class='sec-marg-out relative']/div[@class='sec-marg-in']/div[@class='content-area-out']/div[@class='content-area-in']/div[@class='content-main left relative']/div[@id='article-ad']/div[1]/div[@id='ac_110238']/div[@class='ac_adbox']/div[@class='ac_adbox_inner']

'ac_container' or 'ac-adbox'

When i go to the page in a browser i see the ad, when i use scrapy to get the html

its a script

```
  <div id="contentad110238"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(d) {
        var params =
        {
           id: "d12cd6f3-b896-443b-9140-07e35e66e222",
           d:  "YmVzdHlsaW5nLmNvbQ==",
           wid: "110238",
           cb: (new Date()).getTime()
        };

    var qs=[];
    for(var key in params) qs.push(key+'='+encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
    var s = d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;
    var p = 'https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http';
    s.src = p + "://api.content.ad/Scripts/widget2.aspx?" + qs.join('&');
    d.getElementById("contentad110238").appendChild(s);
})(document);
</script>                                                       </div>
```

How do i scrape this?  Any help would be appreciated...  Im guessing i have to use a js renderer in python or scrapy....  Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Those ads are fetched via Javascript so when you download raw HTML (like Scrapy does) you won't see them.

Although, you can take a look at [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) (formerly ScrapyJS) with [Scrapy integration](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash) to seamlessly embed browser with Javascript. Directly from Scrapy developers.

Everything is in Python, except Qt for browser rendering.

Comment: am i correct in my assumption though?  That i will have to render, ie. is that why its not showing?